# How can I keep as much SVG functionality as possible

Tags: css, svg, cross-browser

I have a snippet of code that in Chrome it works very nicely it has a zipper effect created by the SVG block inside of a PHP for loop

here is the code snippet

```
                <g transform='translate(0,-2)'> 
            <polygon transform='scale(0, 0)'
                    id='tester'
                     points='".$blk*$x.",".$yy." ".($blk*$x+40).",".$yy." ".($blk*$x+50).",".($yy+10)." ".($blk*$x+40).",".($yy+20)." ".$blk*$x.",".($yy+20)." ".($blk*$x+20).",".($yy+10)."'
                     style='stroke:none; 
                     fill:#ffff00;'
                     style='fill: #ffff00'>
                       <animateTransform attributeName='transform' 
                        type='scale'
                        to='1, 1'
                        begin='".($x/15)."s'
                        dur='.5s'
                        fill='freeze'
                        />          
            </polygon>
            </g>
```

This is inside of a for loop no as I said it works in chrome but in firefox safari IE/Edge not so much

I had to add this style block in order to simulate as best I could something flashy in the other browsers

```
    <style>
#tester {
    -webkit-animation:mover .5s;
    animation: mover .5s;
}
@keyframes mover {
    0% {
        transform: scale (0);
        -webkit-transform: scale(0);            
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale (1);
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    }

}

</style>
```

In addition to this I also had to modify the SVG block to have the original scale  to 1,1

```
<polygon transform='scale(1, 1)'
```

This allows the other browsers to somewhat work by simple motion but in doing so CHROME loses the flashiness as well

I need to know how to maintain the original flashiness of the original code and modify the additional style block to all for the less flashiness to still occur in the browsers other than chrome
I have been struggling the last few days on this and this was the best I came up with but I did lose the flashy chrome aspect so the result is not the best.

To answer the first comment I edited this question and added the information requested I had it in comments but moved them all here:

In the original code the first block of code in the loop caused the graphics to be displayed all at a scale of 0 or nothing all iterations of the loop started there as the iterations occurred the x position and y position were increased as was the scale due to the animateTransform the result was that the graphic blocks all started at 0,0 scale transformed to full size (1,1) as they moved along the x and y axis.
The y axis changes stopped early in the iteration so it looked like a zipper being closed with the bottom half of the zipper being stable( the end of the y motion) and the translation in both scale and x position being the other half of the zipper.

Flashiness refers to the zipper effect or lack there of

In order to make it as cross browser compatible as I could I had to add the style tag which killed the whole zipper effect in Chrome.

Now the scale is set to full size at the onset(1,1) and all the iterations show up at x =0, y=0 and it simply slides down into position following the style tag according to the the changes in x and y. The end result is the same look but no zipper effect.

The zipper was working because in the original code the animateTransform functioned inside the loop no it can because there is nothing to transform it starts at scale (1,1) and ends there as well.

If the original code without the style block is in place NO images appear because the scale is always at zero and the other browsers do not understand the animateTransform attribute of the SVG block

Comment: What is a "zipper effect"? What is "flashiness"? Please use technical terms to describe what you want to achieve, and what goes wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You say a loop in PHP produces multiple polygon elements. According to what you show, they all have `id="tester"`, which is not valid XML, ids need to be unique.

For what you want to achieve, use a `class="tester"` instead and change the CSS selector to `.tester`.

Comment: thank you very good point I made that change and it seems a bit smoother, sorry to say it did not affect the zipper aspect much